# What is the need for writing `\n` in this grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression, macos

I was trying to search for lines that start with `create` and end in `;`. The match may span multiple lines. I was trying to use *grep* for that and after searching internet I found out how to do it.

The following query does it

```bash
grep -zioE 'create (\w|\W|\n)*?;' Day1.sql  | less


# Output
create schema sigmoid_db;
create table instructor(
ID char(5),
name varchar(20),
dept_name varchar(20),
salary numeric(8,2));
```

What I want to ask why wouldn't the same query without `\n` work? Like the following query should produce the same output

```bash
grep -zioE 'create (\w|\W)*?;' Day1.sql  | less

# Output
create schema sigmoid_db;
```

My reasoning is `\w|\W` should match any character. But the second command doesn't print the patterns that span multiple lines.

Can anyone tell why so?

Comment: In any case `*?` for non-greedy `*` is a perl operator. Very few `grep` implementations support it with `-E`.

Comment: Try `pcregrep -Mio '(?s)^\h*create .*?;'`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I am not asking for query. I want to understand the behaviour of the queries. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: I can't reproduce with GNU grep 3.7

Comment: This is my grep version `grep (BSD grep, GNU compatible) 2.6.0-FreeBSD`

Comment: Can you possibly reduce it to a smaller reproducer? Like does `printf 'a\nb' | grep -zEo 'a\Wb'` match for you?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/commit/e898a3af97f97f74c0fb22032bbd163f7cc92a05

Comment: FWIW with `2.5.1-FreeBSD` on FreeBSD 12.3, I find that `printf 'a\nb' | grep -zEo 'a\Wb'` matches. `printf 'a\nb' | grep -zEo a.b` also matches in that it reports a zero exit status, but outputs nothing which looks very much like a bug.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `printf 'a\nb' | grep -zEo 'a\Wb'` doesn't work and neither does `printf 'a\nb' | grep -zEo 'a.b'`. I am using Mac.

Answer (score -1):

The `\n` symbol is a Carriage Return. That is a special symbol which separates one line from another.

Any text file is actually a one long string like:

```
first\nsecond\nthird\n
```

which is printed on the screen as

```
first
second
third
```

The `grep` splits the input file into lines and process them one by one. If you want to have a multi-line pattern to be found you must use `\n` in the appropriate place of regular expression.

That is why the pattern `create (\w|\W)*?;` found only a single-line match.

And no, control symbols (and `\n` is one of them) are not considered to be a member of groups "letter" (`\w`) or "non-letter" (`\W`). They are in a group of their own and have to be used by itself.

Comment: I tried my expression on online regex, it works fine. `\W` means any character other than [a-zA-Z0-9_] which includes `\n` as well.

Comment: @Dhruv Yes, that is possible. There are several regexp variations. With `grep` you can choose one of the four major regexp dialects (keys `-E`, `-F`, `-G`, `-P`). And even then, by using different versions of `grep` you can encounter differences in regexp processing. Your `grep` in "extended" mode (you have `-E` key in the command) does not include `\n` in `\W`. The online regexp checker most likely using javascript or Perl versions - they do include it. Run your command with `-P` instead of `-E` and see the difference.

Comment: I think it's a bug related to `\n` as pointed out by @`Stéphane Chazelas`. Because I tried a similar thing for `\t` and it worked. eg - `echo $'a\tb\nc\td' | grep -zEo 'c[^;]*d'` outputs `c[8 spaces]d` but `echo $'a\tb\nc\td' | grep -zEo 'a[^;]*d'` outputs nothing.

Comment: @Dhruv No bugs. Your sample string is treated as two separate lines by `grep` : "a\tb" and "c\td". So it can find pattern which includes "c" and "d", but letters "a" and "d" are on different lines - so nothing is found.

Comment: No I used `-z` flag so it doesn't treat the input as two separate lines. eg - `echo $'a\nb' | grep -z '\n' | less` the output is ```a
b
^@``` (each in a new line).
`^@` [represents null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character). The input is treated as null terminated string. So `\n` matches a part of line and grep prints the matching line (the whole line itself).

Comment: Even `echo $'a\tb\nc\td' | grep -z 'c[^;]*d' | less` prints all the four characters, with tabs, newline and `^@`(at the end).