# Grep with `\n` in C style quoted string prints every line in file

Tags: grep, macos

I was trying to solve some problem for searching using grep when I encountered this weird thing.

Suppose my file1.txt has these two lines

```
hello
to you
```

Whenever I

```bash
grep $'a\n' file1.txt

# Output
hello
to you

grep -o $'a\n' file1.txt

# Output
# Nothing

grep $'a\nb' file1.txt

# Output
# Nothing
```

Wouldn't $`a\n` mean `a` followed by newline, which is not in file but it still prints whole file. Why is this so?

P.S. - Even with `-z` option the behaviour is same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've added details, is this fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` accepts a list of "patterns" (i.e. one or more), separated by newline,
so `grep $'a\n' infile` is the equivalent of

```
grep 'a
' infile
```

or `grep -e 'a' -e '' infile`,
so you are providing the pattern `a` (with no matches in this case)
and then a null pattern `''` [which matches every line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340417). 
It's also mentioned in the [GNU Grep Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Usage-1):

> 11. Why does the empty pattern match every input line?
>
>     The ‘grep’ command searches for lines that contain strings that
>     match a pattern.  Every line contains the empty string,
>     so an empty pattern causes ‘grep’ to find a match on each line.

---

`grep $'a\nb'` is the equivalent of

```
grep 'a
b' infile
```

or `grep -e 'a' -e 'b' infile`. 
Since there are no matches in your input, nothing is printed.

---

You ask

> Since `''` matches every line then why doesn't `-o` print anything?

The [GNU man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) says (emphasis mine):

> **`-o`**, **`--only-matching`**
>
>   Print only the matched
>   ***(non-empty)***
>   parts of a matching line…

I don't have access to OSX right now
but I'm pretty sure their man page mentions this too… 
It's also in the [GNU Grep Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control-1). 
Since the matched part of the matching lines *is empty,* nothing is printed.

Comment: Since `''` matches every line then why doesn't `-o` print anything?

Comment: I found out this [The grep command searches for lines that contain strings that match a pattern. Every line contains the empty string, so an empty pattern causes grep to find a match on each line](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Usage.html). So `''` matches empty string present in each line and also prints the match which is `nothing`. You can add this explanation to your answer.

Comment: Also, I have another question regrading grep [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735036/what-is-the-need-for-writing-n-in-this-grep). Could you please look into that? I have been stuck on it for 2 days.